# Performance of ListView.click vs Button.Click

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

We are having problems with the speed in parts of our application, Standard .NET 4 Windows forms application. We have a ListView containing some commerce items and the user can click on items to put them in a shopping cart. The problem is that when clicking 10 times fast on one item, only 4-6 items is added to the shopping cart.

I get the same result when building a simple test application with only one ListView, with one item and a debug.print in the click handler. 
I have tried to add a Button in the same testapplication and this is fast..

Results from dotTrace Performance:
ListView.click:

```
100,00 %   OnRun  •  6 454 ms  •  Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun
  100,00 %   RunMessageLoop  •  6 454 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, ApplicationContext)
    100,00 %   RunMessageLoopInner  •  6 454 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, ApplicationContext)
      100,00 %   FPushMessageLoop  •  6 454 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
        17,87 %   [Native code]  •  1 153 ms
          17,87 %   Callback  •  1 153 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
            17,87 %   WndProc  •  1 153 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&)
              17,87 %   OnMessage  •  1 153 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&)
                17,87 %   WndProc  •  1 153 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message&)
                  ►17,54 %   WmMouseDown  •  1 132 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WmMouseDown(Message&, MouseButtons, Int32)
                  ►0,33 %   WndProc  •  21 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&)
```

Button.click:

```
100,00 %   OnRun  •  5 931 ms  •  Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun
  100,00 %   RunMessageLoop  •  5 931 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, ApplicationContext)
    100,00 %   RunMessageLoopInner  •  5 931 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, ApplicationContext)
      100,00 %   FPushMessageLoop  •  5 931 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
        0,44 %   [Native code]  •  26 ms
          0,44 %   Callback  •  26 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
            0,44 %   WndProc  •  26 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&)
              0,44 %   OnMessage  •  26 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&)
                0,44 %   WndProc  •  26 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&)
                  0,44 %   WndProc  •  26 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&)
                    0,44 %   WndProc  •  26 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&)
                      ►0,25 %   WmMouseDown  •  15 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message&, MouseButtons, Int32)
                      ►0,10 %   WmMouseUp  •  6 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&, MouseButtons, Int32)
                      ►0,08 %   WmPaint  •  5 ms  •  System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message&)
```

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Hard to reverse-engineer code from a profile output dump.  If you want to support fast clicking then you need to implement the DoubleClick event as well :)

Comment: The test application contains a listview with one column and one item. And This code:  `Private Sub ListView1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.Click
        Debug.Print("testclick!")
    End Sub`

Comment: Seems like handling the DoubleClick event as well is the solution, I'll try and see if that fixes my problem.

Comment: Handling both Click and DoubleClick solved my problem!

Comment: @HugoDrax if that is indeed the answer, please submit a detailed explanation of the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant suggested i need to handle both ListView.Click and ListView.DoubleClick.

Answer (score 0):

Try Mouse_ClickEvent

```
 private void ListView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewHitTestInfo li = lvTracks.HitTest(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        if (li != null)
        {
            if (li.Item != null)
            {
             ListViewItem l=li.Item;
                //do something with l
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried ListView.MouseClick, and get the same results as ListView.Click